# CIFS - Default security mechanism requested (Mounted Share)

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

The following message appear every time I reboot/boot my ubuntu 12.04.1

> CIFS VFS: default security mechanism requested. The default security mechanism will be upgraded from nbtlm to ntlmv2 in kernel realese 3.3

I'am searching for a solution, if there is one for this message, I really don't understand it.

Following my fstab

> //192.168.0.10/D$/ /mnt/winshare/ cifs user,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,rw,gid=1000,credentials=/root/creds 0 0

I can use my mounted folder with no problem, I just want to know why this message is appearing and if have something that I can do to fix this problem or hide this warning.

Thanks

John sent a answer, saying to add the option "sec=ntlmv2", this solved him problem, but unfortunally to me when I try to mount appear "mount error(22): Invalid argument"

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling and asking here and there, I found the answer.

I'm using "sec=ntlmssp" instead of "sec=ntlvm2"

```
//charles.codex/Documents/ /mnt/charles cifs user,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,rw,gid=1000,nounix,sec=ntlmssp,credentials=/root/credentials/charles 0 0
```

This was commented at  [Problem with mount using option "sec=ntlmv2"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405493/problem-with-mount-using-option-sec-ntlmv2)

Answer (score 3):

Add sec=ntlmv2 to your line in fstab like so:

```
//192.168.0.10/D$/ /mnt/winshare/ cifs user,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,rw,gid=1000,sec=ntlmv2,credentials=/root/creds 0 0
```

I had the same issue for a long time, finally fixed it today.

Comment: John, Just one problem, when I try to mount it returns "mount error(22): Invalid argument", have heard about this error? can help me?

Comment: Your fstab line has "user" in it, but if you check the man page for mount.cifs you will see that this should be specified as "user=arg" (where "arg" is the username to connect as).  If that doesn't resolve, try mounting the share manually with mount.cifs and use the --verbose flag to get details.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace **user** option with **guest**.
This is my /etc/fstab:

```
//my_laptop/public /home/user/winshare cifs guest,rw......
```

And this message not appears at boot.

Comment: The OP also has the option `credentials=...` so I don't think logging in as a guest to the share will help as he probably needs credentials.

Comment: As "qertvdijk" said I need credentials, so I can't use guest option.