# Problem with mount using option "sec=ntlmv2"

Tags: fstab, cifs

I Have a partition called D:\ shared at a Windows machine, and In my Ubuntu server 12.4 I Have this line at fstab to mount it

```
//10.0.0.39/D$/ /mnt/charles/ cifs user,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,rw,gid=1000,sec=ntlmv2,credentials=/root/creds 0 0
```

I've added the option "sec=ntlmv2", because was appearing this message every time I boot/reboot my ubuntu.

```
CIFS VFS: default security mechanism requested. The default security mechanism will be upgraded from nbtlm to ntlmv2 in kernel realese 3.3
```

Now I can't mount with this "sec=ntlmv2" option, because appear to me.

```
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

This is the result with --verbose, what this can help to find the problem?

```
root@PITCAIRN:/mnt# mount -t cifs //10.0.39/D$/ /mnt/charles --verbose -ouser=Yamash,sec=ntlmv2 
Password: 
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.0.0.39,unc=\\10.0.39\D$,sec=ntlmv2,ver=1,user=Yamash,pass=********
mount error(22): Invalid argument 
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

--EDIT--
Zetrocker came with the solution, I changed the "sec=ntlmv2" to "sec=ntlmssp" and now it's working.

Thanks Zetrocker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
//10.0.0.39/D$ /mnt/charles cifs --verbose user,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,rw,gid=1000,sec=ntlmv2,credentials=/root/creds 0 0
```

This should at least be a bit more verbose.

There is a thread found at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734400/what-does-cifs-mount-failed-w-return-code-22-indicate)

There are a good number of people that had success after installing the cifs-utils

code:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Comment: This is the result with --verbose, what this can help to find the problem?  
`root@PITCAIRN:/mnt# mount -t cifs //10.0.39/D$/ /mnt/charles --verbose -ouser=Yamash,sec=ntlmv2  
Password:  
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=10.0.0.39,unc=\\10.0.39\D$,sec=ntlmv2,ver=1,user=Yamash,pass=********  
mount error(22): Invalid argument  
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)  `

Comment: The error 22 is evidently a very vague message. It looks like your UNC address is not in a proper format. if not the \\COMPUTERNAME then make it the IP address again.

Comment: I also added a possible solution above. There are some other solutions in that thread, including checking windows permissions and using `samba-client`

Comment: I will read this thread you mentioned, because I already have cifs-utils installed and updated, I tried to use the machine name instead of IP and I got the error, `mount error: could not resolve address for CHARLES: Unknown Error` this could be a problem in Windows?

Comment: I can mount without the option `sec=ntlmv2` or with `sec=ntlm`, but not with `sec=ntlmv2`

Comment: I found a thread that says that the `sec=ntlmssp` option will work in lieu of ntlmv2 [source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1992050)

Comment: The `--verbose` option doesn't seem to work for me on Ubuntu 16.04.  I just get a parse error every time I try to run `sudo mount -a`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment in the accepted answer, adding sec=ntlmssp to my mount options worked for me.

I had CIFS mounts working and added in /etc/fstab, then one day they were failing to connect and the AD account used for auth had become locked. After having the account unlocked, the account was still failing to auth when attempting to mount.

Troubleshooting - using smbclient to list the share information using the same account that was failing in the mount command.

```
sudo smbclient -L service -A /root/credentials.txt
```

This command listed the available shares successfully but running

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/root/credentials.txt //server/share /mnt/share
```

was failing with a permission denied error. I was also seeing this error in /var/sys/messages

```
Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
```

This page was helpful in resolving and at least partially explaining what happened. https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=7015602

Apparently a windows admin may have added extended security which may explain why initially my mount was fine, but then later needed an additional setting.

Original /etc/ftab entry which worked for a time

```
//server/share /mnt/share cifs _netdev,credentials=/root/credentials.txt,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,noperm 0 0
```

New /etc/fstab entry with sec=ntlmssp added

```
//server/share /mnt/share cifs _netdev,sec=ntlmssp,credentials=/root/credentials.txt,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,noperm 0 0
```